# How to embed a YouTube video into a Google Play app which starts from a specific time?

Tags: android, youtube, google-play

For e.g.:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7HKoqNJtMTQ#t=1m25s

It works but when I add it to the Google Play (promo video option) it seems that `#t=1m25s` part is being ignored.

Is there any other way how to archieve the exact same behavior but with different URL?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see immediately wrong is the #.  That should be a &.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YGV92nxP_N0&t=1s

Comment: Thank you for your advice but unfortunately it does work both, just not on the Google Play.